# I am getting error 2 in my winreg function

Tags: c++, registry, winreg

My code:

```cpp
HKEY hKey;
char *path = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001\\HwProfileGuid";
LONG result = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
QString q = QString::number(result);

if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    QMessageBox messageBox1;
    messageBox1.critical(0,"Error", "Success");
    messageBox1.setFixedSize(500,200);
} else {
    QMessageBox messageBox2;
    messageBox2.critical(0,"Error", q);
    messageBox2.setFixedSize(500,200);
}
```

The error I am getting:

[image]

Where the key is in my Registry:

[image]

I think the problem is related to the way I put the info in the `path` variable, but I am not sure.

Comment: This error means the system cannot find this registery

Comment: @coderx64 I know, but I don't know what I've done wrong since the key exists as shown in the last image.

Comment: You specify the parameter `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Try changing the path to start with "SYSTEM\\....."?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I had already tried that, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You have `HwProfileGuid` in the wrong place.

`HwProfileGuid` is a *value* inside of the `0001` key, but you are trying to open `HwProfileGuid` as a *sub-key* of `0001` instead, which is why you are getting error 2 (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`), because there is no *sub-key* named `HwProfileGuid`.

Also, `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` is too many rights to request just to read a value from a key.  Use `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` instead.  Don't request more rights than you actually need.

Try this:

```cpp
const char *path = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001";
const char *valueName = "HwProfileGuid";
char guid[40] = {0};

HKEY hKey;
LONG result = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    DWORD size = sizeof(guid);
    result = RegQueryValueExA(hKey, valueName, NULL, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(guid), &size);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}

QMessageBox messageBox;
if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    messageBox.critical(0, "Success", guid);
} else {
    messageBox.critical(0, "Error", QString::number(result));
}
messageBox.setFixedSize(500, 200);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`RegGetValueA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluea) instead of using
`RegOpenKeyExA()`+`RegQueryValueExA()`:

```cpp
const char *path = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001";
const char *valueName = "HwProfileGuid";
char guid[40] = {0};
DWORD size = sizeof(guid);
QMessageBox messageBox;

LSTATUS result = RegGetValueA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, valueName, RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, guid, &size);
if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    messageBox.critical(0, "Success", guid);
} else {
    messageBox.critical(0, "Error", QString::number(result));
}
messageBox.setFixedSize(500, 200);
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was it, but I will also have to change the value, so I need to get all access.

Comment: @El_Sapo_Pepe no, you simpy need to use `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead. `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` only works for admins, don't use it unless your *really* need *all* access, which is very rare. Again, do not ask for more permissions than you *actually* need. See [Registry Key Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights)

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass `Computer\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to the string. just `SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001` Because HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE are exist in RegOpenKey First Parameter. And dont try to open the value of key just the key RegSetKeyValue() For writing value of key
here the working code:

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG result = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
cout << result << "\n";
```

Comment: I had already tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: @El_Sapo_Pepe your trying to open value not key itself RegOpenKey() for opening key then RegSetKeyValue() For setting value.