# Getting error 87 (INVALID_PARAMETER) when executing RegGetValueA

Tags: c++, registry, winreg

My code:

```
HKEY hKey;
char *path = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001";
LONG result1 = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
QString q = QString::number(result1);

if (result1 == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    LPDWORD b {};
    char *buffer[250];
    LONG result12 = RegGetValueA(hKey, path, "HwProfileGuid", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, &buffer, b);

    if (result12 == ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        QMessageBox messageBox1;
        messageBox1.critical(0,"Error", "Sucesso");
        messageBox1.setFixedSize(500,200);
    } else {
        QString q = QString::number(result12);
        QMessageBox messageBox2;
        messageBox2.critical(0,"Error", q);
        messageBox2.setFixedSize(500,200);
    }


} else {
    QMessageBox messageBox2;
    messageBox2.critical(0,"Error", q);
    messageBox2.setFixedSize(500,200);
}
```

I am a beginner and I am unsure of what parameter is the invalid one.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using [the code I gave you yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67375791/65863) for this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hey! Sorry, I hadn't seen you had included this part of the code in the answer, my bad :(

Answer (score 1):

[RegGetValueA function (winreg.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluea) says:

> The pcbData parameter can be NULL only if pvData is NULL.

Your `pvData` is `&buffer`, which won't be `NULL`, but your `pcbData` is `b`, which is initialized to `NULL`. Therefore this condition is not satisfied.

Also there looks like more errors:

- The parameter should be a pointer where the length of buffer passed to `pvData` is stored.
- It looks weird to use an array of pointer as the buffer to receive the data.
- the key to read is already specified for `RegOpenKeyExA`, so you shouldn't specify that for `RegGetValueA` again. Otherwise, it will try to read the path under the path (`SYSTEM\...\0001\SYSTEM\...\0001`).

The part

```
LPDWORD b {};
char *buffer[250];
LONG result12 = RegGetValueA(hKey, NULL, "HwProfileGuid", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, &buffer, b);
```

should be

```
char buffer[250];
DWORD b = sizeof(buffer);
LONG result12 = RegGetValueA(hKey, path, "HwProfileGuid", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, buffer, &b);
```

Comment: Hey! That fixed error 87, but now I am getting error 2, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: error 2 looks like `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, according to [System Error Codes (0-499) (WinError.h) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). Check if the key and value to read exists. Also check if your program has enough privilege to read that. Another possibility is your code is forced to read another place than expected due to WOW64.

Comment: Ah, The key is already specified for `RegOpenKeyExA`, so the 2nd parameter should be `NULL` to have it read from the key opened.